# Character replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following string value.

```
var stringVal = [4|4.6]^Size{1}~[6];
```

I want to replace everything before the first `^` occurrence with `[1|5]` how do I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

A simple regex will do:

```
var stringVal = '[4|4.6]^Size{1}~[6]';
stringVal.replace(/^.*?\^/, '[1|5]^');
#=> "[1|5]^Size{1}~[6]"
```

Regex explanation:

```
 ^   start of string
 .   any character
 *?  repeat >= 0 times, but match as less characters as possible (non-greedy)
 \^  match '^' (a simple `^` matches the start of the string, so we need to escape it
```

Another, faster way, which would work for this case:

```
'[1|5]' + stringVal.substr(stringVal.indexOf('^'))
```

Comment: @MohammadAdil, I guess I should do that in every answer, many people appreciate it. :)